# Netlogo Code Framework: Opinion Formation Process and Replicator Dynamics/ESS

Tags: netlogo, game-theory

i've got a relative specific question concerning modelling a game theoretical framework. 
To be honest i'm not very versed in programming in Netlogo and got the basic code Setup from an Youtube Video.

But to expand my framework, which i used for my bachelor thesis, i wanted to simulate off-equilibrium dynamics and see whats happens:

First the Model which i considered for my bachelor thesis:

One individuum has the choice between two opionios where one stands for the public opinion wherease one for any other contrary opinion.
So the strategy space is given by S = (A,B) more or less
The Individuum gets a payoff, depending of the share of the population choosing the same strategy A or B 
So the payoff fct. for representing opinion A in the public (public opinion) is given by U(A)= x * a with x; the share and a; any positive number standing for the conformity effect or utlity of being of the same opinion as my friends/neighbours etc.

But the agents have a basic disposition for disagree with the public opinion what is given by their index i.
That means if we assume (for simplicity) all agents are equally distributed on the intervall from 0 to 1 agents, agents near by 1 are in this sense instrinsically more unhappy wherease agents near to 0 are intrinsic more satisfied with the public opinion.

So the payoff fct. for opinion B is given by U(B) = (1-x)*a + i*b with i as the index just mantioned and b again any positive number giving an additional utility for "following" their basic disposition

In my bachelor thesis i came up with a equilibrium analysis where you could see that even if there is only a small group of people beeing for opinion B, it can lead to a chain reaction where the public opinion is changing all over. Of course depending on the variable values chosen.

So my idea of simulating this was now the following:
The payoff depending on the share of population i wanted to cover with evolutionary game Theory/Replicator Dynamics and see what happens. I think a 2x2 payoff matric with 1 or any other positive number on the diagonal and 0 else should be enough (In the recent Code is still a 3x3 Matric).

But how can i model agents distributed equally on the intervall from 0 to 1 and then insert their indice into the payoff matric?

I know it sounds lazy but could anybody set me up the necessary code line? It would be giantic help for my Research.

I hope it was understandable and i'm very interested in your tips, improvement suggestions and critics.

Thanks a lot!

Best Regards,
Rafael

```
globals [
  colors; all the colors/actions
  payments
  old-red-count
  old-green-count
  old-blue-count
]

to setup
  ca
  set colors [red green blue]
  set payments [
  [1 0 0]
  [0 1 0]
  [0 0 1]
  ]
  ask patches [set pcolor white]
  create-turtles num-turtles [
  set color one-of colors
  setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
  ]
reset-ticks
end
to-report payoff [a b]
  set a position a colors
  set b position b colors
  report item b (item a payments)
end

to-report u [action]
  let result 0
  foreach colors [
      let theta count turtles with [color = ?] / count turtles
      set result result + (theta * payoff action ? )
      ]
  report result
end

to go
  tick
  let current-population-count map [count turtles with [color = ?] ] colors      
  let new-population-count (map [?1 * (1 + u ?2)] current-population-count colors) 
  set new-population-count map [num-turtles * ? / sum new-population-count] new-population-count        
  ask turtles [die]
  (foreach new-population-count colors [
     create-turtles ?1 [
       set color ?2
       setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
     ]  
 ])
end
```

Comment: Please add the code in readable form, as a text, to the question

Comment: Thanks, Code is now hopefully written in readable form

Comment: Is the main point of your question "But how can i model agents distributed equally on the intervall from 0 to 1 and then insert their indice into the payoff matric?" If so, can you clarify what you mean by "insert their indice into the payoff matric"? I am having trouble understanding what specifically you're trying to do, it may help if you provide an example of your expected output for a few turtles.

Comment: Hey Luke, thanks for your Reply and sorry for my incomprehensible Explanation.
What i meant is that if we assume that the turtles with the indice i are equally distributed on the intervall i e [0,1] and playing always one against one, there payoff matric is given by  [a 0] first row and [0 a+i*b] second row. What i tried to emphasize is, that in contrast to a symmetric game, deciding against public opinion is accompanied with an additional payoff depending on their Position the intervall (0,1).

Comment: My Question is in this sense split into two parts: How do i link my turtles with this distribution and how do i have to Change my payoff matric to include this Addition Utility depending on their Position in the distribution? 
a and b are should be arbitrarily Chosen.